# Quiero guardar cada elemento de un array que me den, la longitud este array no siempre es la misma

Tags: javascript

Quiero crear una función que me permita guardar cada elemento de un array en variables diferentes, este arrays es el resultado de varias condicionales y por esto el array a destructurar no tiene siempre la misma longitud o los mismo elementos, y es por esto que no encuentro un método para destructurarlo.

```
var todos = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9...]
 
// debería generar el siguiente resultado

var a = [2]
var b = [3]
var c = [4]
var d = [6]
var e = [8]
var f = [9]
var ? = [?]...
```

Comment: Hee...... que??

Comment: Lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Describe el problema puntual que tienes con el código y lo que has intentado

Comment: Por favor añade un poco mas de contexto, en cómo quieres usar esas variables? Seguro hay una estructura de datos que se ajuste a tus necesidades, pero primero danos un poco mas de contexto sobre tu problema

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.